# Error summary in Valgrind output?

Tags: debugging, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind, kcachegrind

I have seen some of the post regarding valgrind but not single post helped me in understanding interpretation of valgrind output. 
I ran two programs with valgrind (Both having memory leaks)

Sample Output for Test 1

```
==20422== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20422== definitely lost: 448 bytes in 3 blocks
==20422== indirectly lost: 786,460 bytes in 1 blocks
==20422== possibly lost: 1,576,052 bytes in 46 blocks
==20422== still reachable: 1,077,107 bytes in 2,333 blocks
==20422== suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20422== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==20422==
==20422== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20422== ERROR SUMMARY: 98307 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
Killed
```

Output for Test 2

```
==20875== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20875== in use at exit: 1,059,198 bytes in 2,047 blocks
==20875== total heap usage: 3,019 allocs, 972 frees, 4,496,090 bytes allocated
==20875==
==20875== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20875== definitely lost: 328 bytes in 2 blocks
==20875== indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20875== possibly lost: 1,600 bytes in 5 blocks
==20875== still reachable: 1,057,270 bytes in 2,040 blocks
==20875== suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20875== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==20875==
==20875== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20875== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

If you look at the error summary, One output says there are errors and other says there are no errors (eventually both have leaks)

My question is - - what is counted as error in valgrind? (valgrind manual didn't helped me)

Comment: You should have had some error messages e.g. invalid read before the leak summary in output 1 but 2 were suppressed

Comment: there was long list of Invalid Read and write in first code.

Comment: Are you using OSX by any chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Memory leaks are not considered errors, they don't effect the logic of the program.

Errors are things such as invalid reads and writes.

Updated as result of comment: The invalid reads and writes in test 1 are for 5 different areas of memory which are accessed 98307 times.

Looking at the leaks, the large indirect losses in test 1 may indicated a linked data structure where only the root has been deleted.

The leaks in test 2 aren't too bad. As valgrind suggests rerun with --leak-check=full which should indicate which bit of code is causing the problem.

A full explanation of the errors can be found [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html)

Comment: Does it mean that in first code there is memory which was not allocated but used and for second code the memory was allocated but not freed.

Comment: You'll have to look at the actual errors, the invalid read just means it's reading somewhere it shouldn't, it could be reading off the end of allocated memory. The leaks are a separate issue - definitely lost, means nothing points to that block of memory so you can't free it, indirectly lost means the pointers are there but in leaked memory themselves and possibly lost means it looks like there is a chain of pointers to the memory, but the intermediate link could be a random value that happens to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have not enough reputation to comment accepted answer, just append some useful info here because I'm searching what is the true error in valgrind report too.

Firstly, errors follow "ERROR SUMMARY" is definitely errors must fixed. **And some leaks also regard as error depend on cmd options used.**

> "if --leak-check=full is specified. Then, the option --errors-for-leak-kinds= controls the set of leak kinds to consider as errors. The default value is --errors-for-leak-kinds=definite,possible"

I found here: https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.errormsgs