# Trying to read leak summary from valgrind - Program causes a segmentation fault on my PC, not on another

Tags: c, ubuntu, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have a C code OpenGL program that compiles and runs fine on my ubuntu machine. But when I compile and run it on another linux it causes a segmentation fault. I've used valgrind to see where the problem could be and here is a small portion of the output:

```
==21294== LEAK SUMMARY:
==21294==    definitely lost: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==21294==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21294==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21294==    still reachable: 191,932 bytes in 1,397 blocks
==21294==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21294== 
==21294== ERROR SUMMARY: 8 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==21294== 
==21294== 1 errors in context 1 of 3:
==21294== Syscall param ioctl(generic) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==21294==    at 0x5936F07: ioctl (syscall-template.S:84)
==21294==    by 0x7C0E0E7: drmIoctl (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==21294==    by 0x7C10DDE: drmCommandWriteRead (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==21294==    by 0xABF2DA0: nouveau_object_mthd (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0)
==21294==    by 0xABF3535: nouveau_device_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0)
==21294==    by 0xA0B9690: nouveau_drm_screen_create (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==21294==    by 0x9C7FD15: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==21294==    by 0x9F6C59B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==21294==    by 0x9F67BD2: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so)
==21294==    by 0x4E80AA2: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==21294==    by 0x4E589C3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==21294==    by 0x4E53F00: glXQueryVersion (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0)
```

The full output file from valgrind is 15614 lines long.
I'm still learning it but I could use assistance on reading what I'm looking at and how I can correct my code. Also this is my first post on this site, so any info for this question and posting in general would be appreciated.

Comment: Start by trying to fix the first error in the output. Later messages may be related to the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation fault has nothing to do with memory leaks. To fix segmentation fault you should read and fix *errors* reported by Valgrind, not *memory leaks*. According to output there are 8 errors found by Valgrind:

```
==21294== ERROR SUMMARY: 8 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

See the difference between Valgrind errors and memory leaks here:
[Error summary in Valgrind output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17398796/72178)